# Trouble casting string to date

Tags: sql-server

I keep getting the following error when running my query and am having trouble finding a solution.

Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

```
select * from creditcard
where cast(left(expdate,2) + '/01/' + right(expdate,2) as date) < '08/01/17'                      
and paycode <> ''
```

All of the dates in the table look like this '07/17'

Comment: MySQL is a database product produced by Oracle. SQL Server is a DBMS produced by Microsoft. They're not the same thing, and it's impossible for you to be running the statement in both of them simultaneously. Which one are you actually using? They have different functionality and syntax differences, so knowing which it is is significant. Please don't tag spam by just randomly adding tags that sound familiar or similar. Use the ones that actually apply to your question.

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @myfakedate varchar(25) = '07/17'

declare @mydatestr varchar(25)

Select @mydatestr = stuff(@myfakedate,3,0,'/01')

select @mydatestr
```

will give you '07/01/17'

Answer (score 0):

If 2012+ user try_convert() just in case you have bogus data.  Otherwise, the standard convert() should do

**Example**

```
Select *
 From  YourTable
 Where try_convert(date,replace(expdate,'/','/01/'))<'08/01/17'
```